# How to fix "Distutils was imported before Setuptools" when opening a .ipynb file?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, setuptools, distutils

If I try to open my Rscript.ipynb file via Windows Explorer I get the following warning and my file does not open.

> c:\Users\kirst\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\distutils_patch.py:25 UserWarning: Distutils was imported before Setuptools. This usage is discouraged and may exhibit undesirable errors. Please use setuptools 'objects directly or at least import setuptools first.

[image: Warning]

If I first open the Jupyter Notebook using a shortcut with the following target

```
C:\Users\kirst\anaconda3\python.exe C:\Users\kirst\anaconda3\cwp.py C:\Users\kirst\anaconda3\envs\R C:\Users\kirst\anaconda3\envs\R\python.exe C:\Users\kirst\anaconda3\envs\R\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py "%USERPROFILE%/"
```

and then open the notebook by browsing to it, I don't have problems.

How do I set up to be able to open the file from explorer?

Answer (score 10):

I found a solution at https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/brian-team/brian2/1213/673490152

You need to upgrade to the latest version:

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools
```

and the warning will disappear.

Comment: The link has unfortunately died :(

Comment: https://github.com/brian-team/brian2/issues/1213#issuecomment-673490152 is the authoritative link. gitmemory.com is an ad-ridden scraper.

Comment: Same error after pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools: /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_distutils_hack/__init__.py:33: UserWarning: Setuptools is replacing distutils.
  warnings.warn("Setuptools is replacing distutils.")

Answer (score 5):

I'm copy-pasting an answer from [a github user with the same problem](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/5689) and this solution
seemed to work like a charm for me.
Here is what you need to type on your command prompt:

> pip uninstall pyzmq

(you might need to confirm the choice by entering y) and once that is done type:

> pip install pyzmq

it might help. I had a similar problem while opening jupyter notebook. that fixed it.

Comment: don't have python in my cmd environment. If I want it I have to activate Anaconda command prompt. Maybe that is my problem.

Answer (score 0):

It can solved by editing `conda_api.py` in `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\api`.

In `load_rc` function, change `data = yaml.load(f)` to  `data = yaml.safeload(f)` (at line 1360)