# UserWarning: Setuptools is replacing distutils. at building Hue : sudo make apps ,it fails with :

Tags: python-3.7, setuptools, distutils, hue, user-warning

### add the development packages, build and get the development server running:

- "PYTHON_VER is python3.7."
- "Python 3 module install via pip"
- "SYS_PYTHON is /root/.pyenv/shims/python3.7."
- "ENV_PYTHON is /data/opt/hue/hue/build/env/bin/python3.7."

added in ~/.bashrc

```
export PYTHON_VER=python3.7
```

then

```bash
git clone https://github.com/cloudera/hue.git
cd hue
make apps
```

```
/data/opt/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_distutils_hack/__init__.py:19: UserWarning: Distutils was imported before Setuptools, but importing Setuptools also replaces the `distutils` module in `sys.modules`. This may lead to undesirable behaviors or errors. To avoid these issues, avoid using distutils directly, ensure that setuptools is installed in the traditional way (e.g. not an editable install), and/or make sure that setuptools is always imported before distutils.
  "Distutils was imported before Setuptools, but importing Setuptools "
/data/opt/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_distutils_hack/__init__.py:33: UserWarning: Setuptools is replacing distutils.
  warnings.warn("Setuptools is replacing distutils.")
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/opt/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/data/opt/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 335, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/data/opt/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/data/opt/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/data/opt/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 634, in _prepare_file
    abstract_dist.prep_for_dist()
  File "/data/opt/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 129, in prep_for_dist
    self.req_to_install.run_egg_info()
  File "/data/opt/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 412, in run_egg_info
    self.setup_py, self.name,
  File "/data/opt/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 387, in setup_py
    import setuptools  # noqa
  File "/data/opt/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    import _distutils_hack.override  # noqa: F401
  File "/data/opt/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_distutils_hack/override.py", line 1, in <module>
    __import__('_distutils_hack').do_override()
  File "/data/opt/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_distutils_hack/__init__.py", line 77, in do_override
    ensure_local_distutils()
  File "/data/opt/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_distutils_hack/__init__.py", line 64, in ensure_local_distutils
    assert '_distutils' in core.__file__, core.__file__
AssertionError: /root/.pyenv/versions/3.7.0/lib/python3.7/distutils/core.py
```

[Answer1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72950907/how-to-fix-userwarning-distutils-was-imported-before-setuptools)

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools
```

[Answer2](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/5689)

```
pip uninstall pyzmq
# then
pip install pyzmq
```

it doesn't work,any idea?

Answer (score 0):

This fixed for me

```
/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install --user --upgrade pip setuptools --disable-pip-version-check
```

link:-

https://discuss.pixls.us/t/latest-version-install-script-errors-on-installation/28479/2