# ImportError: cannot import name 'JSONDecodeError' from 'simplejson' (unknown location) while creating conda environment?

Tags: python, conda, environment, anaconda3

I am trying to create a conda environment using a yml file on a remote linux server.

I run the command  `conda env create --name env1 -f environment.yml`.

I first tried with miniconda3 installed on the server. Then I get the following errors after running the above command.

```
/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_distutils_hack/__init__.py:33: UserWarning: Setuptools is replacing distutils.
  warnings.warn("Setuptools is replacing distutils.")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/gateways/connection/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from requests import ConnectionError, HTTPError, Session
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    from .exceptions import RequestsDependencyWarning
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/exceptions.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .compat import JSONDecodeError as CompatJSONDecodeError
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/compat.py", line 40, in <module>
    from simplejson import JSONDecodeError
ImportError: cannot import name 'JSONDecodeError' from 'simplejson' (unknown location)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/miniconda3/bin/conda-env", line 6, in <module>
    from conda_env.cli.main import main
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda_env/cli/main.py", line 13, in <module>
    import conda.exports  # noqa
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/exports.py", line 24, in <module>
    from . import plan  # noqa: F401
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/plan.py", line 24, in <module>
    from .core.index import LAST_CHANNEL_URLS, _supplement_index_with_prefix
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/core/index.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .package_cache_data import PackageCacheData
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/core/package_cache_data.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .path_actions import CacheUrlAction, ExtractPackageAction
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/core/path_actions.py", line 30, in <module>
    from ..gateways.connection.download import download
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/gateways/connection/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.requests import ConnectionError, HTTPError, Session
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._vendor.requests'
```

Then I installed anaconda3 and run the command again. then I get the following error.

```
/home/ebrar.bozkurt/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_distutils_hack/__init__.py:33: UserWarning: Setuptools is replacing distutils.
  warnings.warn("Setuptools is replacing distutils.")
/home/ebrar.bozkurt/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_distutils_hack/__init__.py:33: UserWarning: Setuptools is replacing distutils.
  warnings.warn("Setuptools is replacing distutils.")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../anaconda3/bin/conda-env", line 6, in <module>
    from conda_env.cli.main import main
  File "/home/e/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda_env/cli/main.py", line 42, in <module>
    from . import main_create
  File "/home/e/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda_env/cli/main_create.py", line 17, in <module>
    from conda.notices import notices
  File "/home/e/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/notices/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .core import notices  # noqa: F401
  File "/home/e/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/notices/core.py", line 15, in <module>
    from . import fetch
  File "/home/e/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/notices/fetch.py", line 8, in <module>
    import requests
  File "/home/e/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    from .exceptions import RequestsDependencyWarning
  File "/home/e/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/exceptions.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .compat import JSONDecodeError as CompatJSONDecodeError
  File "/home/e/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/compat.py", line 40, in <module>
    from simplejson import JSONDecodeError
ImportError: cannot import name 'JSONDecodeError' from 'simplejson' (unknown location)
```

I searched for the solutions and found [How to fix "Distutils was imported before Setuptools" when opening a .ipynb file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66511643/how-to-fix-distutils-was-imported-before-setuptools-when-opening-a-ipynb-file) with  similar error and applied the solution of using `pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools`. However, this does not solve my issue.
How to resolve this error and what did I do wrong?
I still have the problem, any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried updating `conda` itself and/or the base conda environment?

Comment: Yes but did not work

Answer (score 4):

The error is raised in requests package.

I've seen the problem on my conda environment after upgrade conda base python from 3.9 to 3.10.

And solved it by upgrade requests package in the conda base environment:

```
pip install --upgrade requests
```

Hope it helps in case somebody runs into the thread.